# Complex Analysis Proof2

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function satisfying $|f(z)|\leq k|z|$ for some positive constants $k$ and all $z$. Show that $f(z)=az^2$ for some constant $a$.

Comment: Something is wrong with the problem statement. A quadratic cannot be bounded in magnitude by a linear expression...

Comment: The function $f(z)/z$ is entire and bounded (it has a removable singularity at the origin). Use Liouville's theorem.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327360/question-on-application-of-liouvilles-theorem/327389#327389) for the correct statement and proof.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Thanks !! btw is there a method to find previously posted questions on this site ?

Answer (score 2):

Your theorem is   off.

Let's suppose that your statement is true and there exists such $a$.
First, if $a\ne 0$, then $|f(z)|=|a||z|^2$ and can not be bounded by $k|z|$ (just take $|z|> k/|a|$). Hence, $a=0$ and $f=0$. But we can always take linear $f(z) = kz$, which are not zero, and are bounded by $k|z|$, hence the contradiction, and you theorem is false.

I think there was a typo somewhere.